# PostgreSQL citext index vs lower expression index performance

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, database-indexes

I want to decide between using a `citext` column with an index or using a `text` column with an index on `lower()`.

I performed some benchmarks. To my surprise the search with the index on `lower()` causes an index scan, but in the `citext` case I get an index only scan. I was expecting the index on `lower()` to cause an index only scan too.

Also, the total cost with the `citext` index is 4.44, but with the index on `lower()`, the total cost is 8.44.

So the first thing coming to my mind is that the `citext` column index is better than the expression index on a `text` column.

```
CREATE TABLE test_citext(a citext NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test_citext
   SELECT cast(x as text)
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x;

VACUUM (FREEZE, ANALYZE) test_citext;

create index citextind on test_citext(a);

Select * from test_citext where a = 'test';
--Index Only Scan.Total cost 4.44

CREATE TABLE test_textlowerindex(a text NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test_textlowerindex
   SELECT cast(x as text)
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x;

VACUUM (FREEZE, ANALYZE) test_textlowerindex;

create index lowertextind on test_textlowerindex(lower(a));

Select * from test_textlowerindex where lower(a) = 'test';
--Index Scan.Total cost 8.44
```

Am I right?

Mister Laurenz Albe thanks for your answer.I changed my above script as you said.
Result :

```
CREATE TABLE test_citext(a citext NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test_citext
   SELECT cast(x as text)
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x;

create index citextind on test_citext(a);

VACUUM (FREEZE, ANALYZE) test_citext;

Select count(*) from test_citext where a = 'test';
--Index Only Scan 4.44 + 4.46

CREATE TABLE test_textlowerindex(a text NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test_textlowerindex
   SELECT cast(x as text)
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS x;

create index lowertextind on test_textlowerindex(lower(a));

VACUUM (FREEZE, ANALYZE) test_textlowerindex;

Select count(*) from test_textlowerindex where lower(a) = 'test';
--Index Scan 8.44 + 8.46
```

But anything did not changed Even If I run analyze after creating index and using count(*) in select.Index Scan still continues with an index on lower().

Comment: I think that reason for this would normally be "index can't convert back lowercased value so it needs to look into table", but SELECT lower(a) won't use Index Only either.

Answer (score 3):

Your test is misleading. There are two problems here:

1. You didn't run `ANALYZE` after creating index `lowertextind`.

   Without that, PostgreSQL doesn't know how `lower(a)` is distributed and will probably produce a wrong cost estimate.
2. By using `SELECT *` you inadvertently allowed an *index only scan* to be used for the first query, but not for the second. This is because the first index contains all table columns, but the second doesn't.

   Since the second index doesn't contain `a`, the value has to be fetched from the table, causing additional work.

   You could use `SELECT count(*) FROM ...` for a fairer benchmark.